# Jib - where to copy webapp folder inside image?

Tags: docker, maven, web-applications, jib

I am creating docker image using google's Jib maven plugin, image gets created successfully and backend services are working fine but my webapp folder is not part of that image. Before jib i was creating a zip containing everything (including webapp folder in the root of that zip along with executable jar) which was working fine.

Now the image created by jib has classes, libs, resources in the app root. How and where should i copy webapp folder ?

Comment: I assume your project is being packaged as a WAR file. Is it a Spring Boot app? If so, try changing it to JAR (remove `<packaging>war</packaging>`) and use a simple JRE base image. If not Spring Boot, what exactly is your base image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me by using external directories provided by maven jib plugin.

```
<extraDirectories>
    <paths>
      <path>webapp</path>
      <path>
        <from>webapp</from>
        <into>/app/webapp</into>
      </path>
    </paths>
</extraDirectories>
```

Comment: Can you provide further explanation? Are you running this as a WAR as a JAR file?

Answer (score 2):

I am currently using running a spring-boot version `2.4.10` and the application is packed as a `jar`.

My project have JSPs at:

`src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`

This is important because it allows me to run the application as an executable jar: `java -jar ./target/app.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod`

`jib-plugin` doesn't copy the `src/main/webapp` directory to the container image by default, so we need to add it manually by including the following configuration.

```xml
<extraDirectories>
   <paths>
      <path>
          <from>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</from>
          <into>/app/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF</into>
      </path>
   </paths>
</extraDirectories>
```

I provide `jib-plugin` a custom `entrypoint.sh`

The `entrypoint.sh` is located at `src/main/jib`

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "The application will start in ${APPLICATION_SLEEP}s..." && sleep ${APPLICATION_SLEEP}
exec java ${JAVA_OPTS} -noverify -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch \
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -cp /app/resources/:/app/classes/:/app/libs/* \
"com.demo.application.Application"  "$@"
```

My final `jib-plugin` configuration is the following:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jib-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <from>
            <image>adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot</image>
        </from>
        <to>
            <image>myprivateregistry/app/${project.name}</image>
            <tags>
                <tag>latest</tag>
                <tag>${project.version}</tag>
            </tags>
        </to>
        <container>
            <entrypoint>
                <shell>bash</shell>
                <option>-c</option>
                <arg>/entrypoint.sh</arg>
            </entrypoint>
            <ports>
                <port>8080</port>
            </ports>
            <environment>
                <SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED>ALWAYS</SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED>
                <APPLICATION_SLEEP>0</APPLICATION_SLEEP>
            </environment>
            <creationTime>USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP</creationTime>
        </container>
        <extraDirectories>
            <paths>
                <path>src/main/jib</path>
                <path>
                    <from>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</from>
                    <into>/app/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF</into>
                </path>
            </paths>
            <permissions>
                <permission>
                    <file>/entrypoint.sh</file>
                    <mode>755</mode>
                </permission>
            </permissions>
        </extraDirectories>
    </configuration>
    <!-- Make JIB plugin run during the packing life cycle -->
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above didn't work for me but the below did.

```
<extraDirectories>
    <paths>
        <path>
            <from>../path/to/frontend/app/dist</from>
            <into>/app/resources/static</into>
        </path>
    </paths>
</extraDirectories>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how it worked for me...
When starting up the application in the console there was following line:

```
.... Starting Application using Java 17.0.2 on cd95e38f003e with PID 1 (/app/classes started by root in /)
```

Then I switched on debug logging for the application and saw that ***DocumentRoot.java*** is scanning ***"src/main/webapp", "public", "static"***

Therefore I added to my pom.xml

```
 <configuration>    
                    <extraDirectories>
                        <paths>
                          <path>
                            <from>src/main/webapp</from>
                            <into>/public</into>
                          </path>
                        </paths>
                    </extraDirectories>
...
```

So, the conclusion would be to provide the jsps in one of these 3 folders.
Edit: My jsps are stored directly on the src/main/webapp folder.